# Prevent disabled users from resetting thier password using Azure Ad B2c custom policies

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a situation where I want to prevent disabled users from resetting their password.

I am trying to put the `OrchestrationStep` in `PasswordReset` user journey, and to show "*account disabled error message*" if the user account is disabled.

Below is my `PasswordReset` user journey, but it is not working as expected.

```
<UserJourney Id="PasswordReset">
    <OrchestrationSteps> 
   
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
            <Preconditions>              
                <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                    <Value>accountEnabled</Value>
                    <Value>false</Value>
                    <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                </Precondition>
            </Preconditions>
            <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAssertedRegErrorAccountCheck" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-Account-Disabled-Error" />
            </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
            <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="PasswordResetUsingEmailAddressExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress" />
            </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
            <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="NewCredentials" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId" />
            </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep> 
        
        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
    </OrchestrationSteps>
    <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
</UserJourney>
```

Updated steps - It's working now.

[image]

Comment: Man thats convoluted .. one would think a disabled user wouldn't be able to get into their account, so they couldn't be able to reset their password.  But somehow they are getting in and doing it ?

Comment: The password reset link is available on the main login page. They are not logging into the system. I want to prevent when user clicks the Password reset link and enters the username(after that we have accountEnabled value).

Comment: But when you click the reset button, does it not ask them for their login information and then deny the reset on a disabled user when submitted?  Or does it automatically do it when you click the button and grabs some domain information to make assumptions about whom is sitting at the keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you haven't read the user account so accountEnabled is never set.

You need to do a AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress first which in your case is in LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress.

**Update**

Take out step 2 - that's for social accounts.

Comment: I added those steps still it doesn't give the desired result.

Comment: Please post the updated "PasswordReset" journey.

Comment: Added a screenshot to the original question since it did not allow me to put that long code here.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to review. Just remove step 2 and leave everything as is?

Comment: Yes, that should fix it.

Comment: that worked. Thank you so much. Was missing the "accountEnabled" output in that technical profile.